# Is there a way to (re)map Laravel Collections with an index from its content?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, mapping, pluck

**I have some Newsletters:**

```
$newsletters = $channel->Newsletter()->whereIn('id', $wantNewsletters)->get();
```

Which result in this collection:

[image]

I tried to use pluck, but it just allows one column:

`$newsletters = $channel->Newsletter()->whereIn('id', $wantNewsletters)->pluck('media', 'id');`

[image]

**What I try to achieve** is this (pardon my sad paintshop skillz :D)
[image]

In a way, that's like `->pluck('*', 'id')`. For now I had to foreach every collection and this does not seem right to me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [keyBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-keyby) method:

```
$newsletters = $channel->Newsletter()->whereIn('id', $wantNewsletters)->get()->keyBy('id');
```

Comment: Awesome, that is it. Thanks a lot!